# Affectiva SDK best practices

Tags: affdex-sdk

Is there some document like development guidelines for Linux platform?

For example questions that I have in my mind after playing a little with the SDK:
1. Does the CameraDetector (or any other detector) should be used in a different thread than the main GUI thread? Is it blocking somehow or is it spawning another thread by itself?
2. When listener notifications are executed - is it the same thread in which detector was created?
3. Is it costly to start and stop detector? Should it be done once when application is started and closed or can it be done on demand when user performs some action on which I should use the detector?

Do other detectors behave the same way?
Are there any other best practices for using the SDK?

Answer (score 1):

`CameraDetector::start()` creates a background thread that connects to the camera and begins processing frames.  `CameraDetector::stop()` signals the background thread to disconnect from the camera, stop processing frames, and shut down.

Thus, there is some overhead to calling `start()` and `stop()`, but whether this is impactful to your main thread's performance is up to you to assess. I would suggest doing on the main thread as an initial approach and see.

Callbacks are made on a background thread.

Regarding the alternatives of (a) starting once at client startup and stopping at client shutdown vs. (b) starting and stopping as needed when there is detection work to be done, there isn't really a single best practice.  As noted, during an active session (i.e. after `start()` and before `stop()`) there are additional resources in use, so this is a factor that may bias things toward (b) if the sessions are infrequent in the larger context of the client application.

In addition, in the specific case of CameraDetector, the camera itself is potentially a hardware resource that other applications would be interested in accessing as well, so minimizing its use would be friendlier to those other applications.